# Xcode 11 - Swift - UILabel backgroundColor not working at viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to set a background color programatically for a UILabel defined in an interface builder (.xib) file when the view controller is loaded (viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear) but it's not working

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

But changing textColor works!

Also, this works only if I do not set a backgroundColor in the interface builder or if I set a delay (even 0 seconds) after viewWillAppear is called. I don't remember having this issue before. I recently moved to Xcode 11.2 (from 10.3) and I already found a lot of issues with default / auto constraints. Could this be the cause? If yes, is there a fix?

Comment: Can you try setting that in viewDidLayoutSubviews | layoutSubviews and see if it works?

Comment: It is working just fine for me. Maybe you're setting a background color somewhere else and it's undoing your green color?

Comment: I have no other reference to label.backgroundColor in the view controller's code. But i tried to set it in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method and it works. Thanks!

Comment: You can put that as an answer if you like. Also, is there somewhere in the docs saying about this behavior? viewDidLayoutSubviews is called when bounds change (or rotating), so for me, this seems counter-intuitive.